# How can I make an em-dash to allow for a linebreak on either side?

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, hyphenation

1. How can I make an em-dash allow a linebreak on either side?
2. Optionally, how do I preserve the hyphenation points of the word on both sides?

The following code allows for `refrigerator---refrigerator` to be line-broken only after the em-dash but nowhere else. (Regarding (2): The word "refrigerator" is hyphenated *re-frig-er-a-tor* according to US hyphenation (see for example [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refrigerator), which is also what LaTeX does.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq refrigerator---refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator refrigerator

\end{document}
```

By the way, if someone knows of the most straightforward way to demonstrate such linebreaking behavior with code, please let me know (something with `\hspace*`? - I'm really looking for the best, shortest way to code such an example). You're welcome to edit my question to that effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace `---` by `\foo` defined by

```
\newcommand\foo{\linebreak[0]---\linebreak[0]}
```

Depending on the effect you want you may also want to add a small amount of stretchable glue.

Comment: I've just tried this out; the hyphenation points of the word on the left are preserved. In order to preserve the ones on the right as well, `\newcommand\foo{\linebreak[0]---\linebreak[0]\hspace{0pt}}` did the trick for me.